# get all fb person name same as given name in facebook ios

Tags: iphone, ios, facebook, facebook-graph-api, ios6

Friends i am developing facebook related application. In my application user can able to search person name. so first i have tried Graph-Api search. i got the list of peoples but some peoples are missing, because they have set privacy setting. But when i type the name in facebook it shows all person where the name is same as given name.

and also list of peoples order is different.

So my issue is

1)NOT getting all users list where same as given name

2) why the ordering of data is different?.

I am using this code for getting person name list

```
    NSMutableDictionary *variables = [NSMutableDictionary dictionaryWithCapacity:2];

    [variables setObject:@"priya" forKey:@"q"];
    [variables setObject:@"user" forKey:@"type"];

   //  [variables setObject:@"post" forKey:@"type"];

        FbGraphResponse *fb_graph_response = [fbGraph doGraphGet:@"search" withGetVars:variables];

       NSLog(@"Raw HTML:  %@", fb_graph_response.htmlResponse);
```

is any other way to get the same result?

Comment: Check user permissions,public-actions accessibility is set,then once again validate access token and check in FBGraph-API validator tool.

Comment: yes some users set private access. but when i search in facebook it is not restricted the persons, but i use facebook graph api it don't show those users.